# Why can't I view or edit Umbraco templates?

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

When I open the Umbraco (7.6.3) backoffice, I'm unable to view or make changes to templates. It seems like other functionality is unaffected, and I can create & edit specific pages. However, attempting to open the templates themselves just leads to a white screen. This problem exists across browsers:
[image: A screen, not showing what it's supposed to]

Other screens render just fine:

[image: a normal looking screen]

What gives?

Checking the console when attempting to load gives an interesting error:

```
Error: Argument 'Umbraco.Editors.Templates.EditController' is not a function, got undefined...
```

[image]

---

### Resolution:

The issue seemed to be caused by outdated files in the `Umbraco` folder. Copying most directories over from `packages\UmbracoCms.7.6.3\UmbracoFiles\umbraco\` seems to have done the trick.
Looking at the changelog, it seems like the `JS` folder was the most influential in getting this fixed.

Comment: Have you tried opening dev tools (F12) to see if any errors occur?

Comment: Error: Argument 'Umbraco.Editors.Templates.EditController' is not a function, got undefined (...

Comment: Hm. Try putting that info in the question itself and see if anybody else can figure it out - I'm drawing a blank there :-/

Comment: Thanks, you save my day :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that you're on 7.6.3? The UI appears to be pre-7.6 (I can tell because the colours haven't been updated).

If you have just upgraded, it's possible that your browser has cached the JS which is used - hard refresh your browser to see if the UI updates.

Umbraco also uses a dependency service to compile all of the used JS/CSS files together into one large one. This service will not be used if your website is in debug mode. Either:

- Turn debug mode on in the `Web.config`
- Delete any files in the `\App_Data\ClientDependency\` folder as this is where the cached compiled files are kept (these will be regenerated)

Comment: You're spot-on about the recent upgrade. However, neither enabling & disabling debug mode in `Web.config` nor clearing out the temp files has cleared up the issue. It's happening across machines, as well, so I don't think that it's browser-specific.

Comment: @UrhoKarila Can you check what version of Umbraco you are on? Click on the question mark at the bottom left of the backoffice UI to check.

Comment: `Umbraco version 7.6.3 assembly: 1.0.6361.21154`

Comment: @UrhoKarila Also, how did you upgrade? Were the `Umbraco` and `Umbraco_Client` folders updated during the upgrade?

Comment: Upgraded through Visual Studio -- used NuGet to get the updated UmbracoCms, let the upgrader do it's thing. It doesn't look like either `Umbraco` nor `Umbraco_Client` were touched during the upgrade.

Comment: Hmm they probably should have updated. You should be able to find these files in `\packages\UmbracoCms.7.6.3\UmbracoFiles`. You could manually update them but there's a possibility of some config changes missing. Maybe revert back to the version you were on before, and upgrade again?

Comment: Winner winner! Replacing outdated files in `Umbraco` seems to have fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

My first thought would be file permissions.

Have you run the health check for permissions in the developer section?  Need to make sure that your application pool user has write permissions on the Views folder.

Comment: It seems like that's all in order. It looks like an Angular issue.